# Full Outer Join on two associative arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have two php arrays as shown below. Now I would like get a full outer join (like in SQL) on these two arrays. "Id" can be considered as unique key. What is the easiet way to achieve this?

Array 1 (old data):

```
array(
[0]=>array("Id"=>101, "Name"=>"Bob",....),
[1]=>array("Id"=>102, "Name"=>"Scott",....),
[2]=>array("Id"=>103, "Name"=>"Philips",....),
[3]=>array("Id"=>104, "Name"=>"Marker",....)
)
```

Array 2 (new data):

```
array(
[0]=>array("Id"=>102, "Name"=>"Scott",....),
[1]=>array("Id"=>103, "Name"=>"Philips",....),
[2]=>array("Id"=>104, "Name"=>"Mark",....),
[3]=>array("Id"=>105, "Name"=>"Nix",....)
)
```

Result Array:

`array(

```
  [0]=>array("Status"=>"d", "Id"=>101, "Name"=>"Bob",....), 
  [1]=>array("Status"=>"s", "Id"=>102, "Name"=>"Scott",....), 
  [2]=>array("Status"=>"s", "Id"=>103, "Name"=>"Philips",....),
  [3]=>array("Status"=>"c", "Id"=>104, "Name"=>"Mark",....),
  [4]=>array("Status"=>"n", "Id"=>105, "Name"=>"Nix",....)
```

)`

where status -->

`"d" - Delete

"s" - Same, no change in record values

"c" - Change in any of the record value(s)

"n" - New record`

Comment: Can we see your current solution? I'd start off with a loop, using `Id` to retrieve the old version in the first array. You can then improve from there if you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may reindex both arrays by putting their "Id" fields as keys

```
     array(
     [101]=>array("Id"=>101, "Name"=>"Bob",....),
     [102]=>array("Id"=>102, "Name"=>"Scott",....),
     [103]=>array("Id"=>103, "Name"=>"Philips",....),
     [104]=>array("Id"=>104, "Name"=>"Marker",....)
     )
```

then cycling the second for each entry in the first, status can be easly decided with some array comparison function for statuses 's' and 'c', array_key_exists for 'd'. The result of
array_diff (array 2, array 1) should retrieve entries with status 'n'

so:

```
     $result = Array();

     foreach(array1 as $k1 => $v1){

       if(!array_key_exists($k1, $array2)){
             $status = 'd';
       }else{
             if(are_the_same($v1, $array2[$k1])) $status = 's';
             else $status = 'c';
       }

       $result[]=array("Status"=>$status, "Id"=>$k1, "Name"=>$v1['Name'],....)

     }
```

then you may use a combination of array merge y array_diff to fill in the 'd' status ones.
I think you can write your own code for this ;-)

Comment: Thanks Laxertu. This code solves my problem