# Replace one array keys with second array values

Tags: php, arrays, function

I need to combine two arrays, the key from the first array should be replaced with the respective value from the second array. The following code works fine if both arrays have the same number of elements and if they have the same order.

```
$first = array("a"=>"red", "b"=>"green", "c"=>"blue");

$second = array("a"=>"sun", "b"=>"grass", "c"=>"sky");

$new = array_combine($second, $first);

print_r($new);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [sun] => red
    [grass] => green
    [sky] => blue
)
```

But I need this to work in a scenario where they don´t have the same elements number or not in the same order. How can I achieve it?

Comment: array_combine() need that parameters should have an equal number of elements

Comment: what do you mean by "But I need this to work in a scenario where they don´t have the same elements number" ??
consider these arrays :
1- $myArrayA = ['a'=>'aa' , 'b' => 'bb']
2- $myArrayB = ['a' => 'cc' , 'd' => 'ff' , 'g' => 'hh']

what is the result of your array combination ??

Comment: @majid8911 Should be `$combination = ['cc'=>'aa' , 'b' => 'bb']`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476577/full-outer-join-on-two-associative-arrays-in-php

Answer (score 0):

If you need to trim your arrays so that you can use `array_combine()` the approach below will make both the same length by trimming the biggest one and then will combine them.

```
$first = array("a"=>"red", "b"=>"green", "c"=>"blue");

$second = array("a"=>"sun", "b"=>"grass", "c"=>"sky", "d" => "moon");

$first = array_slice($first, 0, count($second));
$second = array_slice($second, 0, count($first));

$new = array_combine($second, $first);

print_r($new);
```

Results in:

```
Array
(
    [sun] => red
    [grass] => green
    [sky] => blue
)
```

It works in all cases:

- `$first` bigger than `$second`.
- `$second` bigger than `$first`.
- `$first` and `$second` has the same size.

Comment: Thanks. But I can't change the first array size. And if they don't have the same order?

Comment: @user4076077 how would you possible combine them, then? Tell us your strategy.

Comment: Can I use something else rather than `array_combine()` ?

Comment: @user4076077 the real issue is to know what you expect as a result when the arrays have different sizes.

Comment: `$first = array("a"=>"red", "b"=>"green", "c"=>"blue"); $second = array("a"=>"sun", "b"=>"grass", "c"=>"sky", "d" => "moon"); $combination = array("sun"=>"red", "grass"=>"green", "sky"=>"blue");`

Comment: @user4076077, that's exactly what my code is doing.

Comment: `$first = array("a"=>"red", "b"=>"green", "c"=>"blue"); $second = array("b"=>"grass", "a"=>"sun", "c"=>"sky", "d" => "moon"); $combination = array("sun"=>"red", "grass"=>"green", "sky"=>"blue");` But I need the same result even when the second array order is different.

Comment: In this case, you would need some kind of logic to know how to link your arrays, otherwise how would you now how to link 'sun' with 'red'?

Comment: Can you give me some guidance to achieve it?

Comment: You could have a lookup array, with all possible results, like: `$lookup = array('sun' => 'red', 'sky' => 'blue');` then you could just look at this array to get your answer.